# $T$ is linear and normal, and $T^2=\frac{T+T^*}{2}$, Prove: $T^2-T=0$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ inner product space from finite dimension under $\mathbb C$ and $T: V\to V$ linear transformation so that $$T^2=\frac{T+T^*}{2}.$$

I proved that is normal and I need also to prove that $T^2-T=0$.

I'd love your help with this.

Thanks!

Comment: Hint: you know that $T$ is normal, so (I presume) you know that it has an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors. Consider what properties its eigenvalues must have.

Comment: Sorry I rolled back just because I was curios to see how does it look before and after, How do I return it?

Answer (score 4):

Since $T$ is normal, both $T$ and $T^*$ are semi-simple (diagonalizable) in the same basis (they commute). Moreover, if $v$ is an eigenvector of $T$ associated with eigenvalue $\lambda$, then $v$ is an eigenvector of $T^*$ associated with eigenvalue $\bar{\lambda}$. This implies that w.r.t the diagonalizing basis $B$ we have $[T]_B=\rm{diag}(\lambda_1,...,\lambda_n)$ and $[T^*]_B=\rm{diag}(\bar{\lambda_1},...,\bar{\lambda_n})$.
Now use the equality $T^2=\frac{1}{2}(T+T^*)$: it holds also in base $B$, so for any eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $T$ you should have $\lambda^2=\frac{1}{2}(\lambda+\bar{\lambda})$. By representing $\lambda=a+ib$ and substituting, we have $a^2=a, b=0$. It follows that $\lambda\in\{0,1\}$. This implies that $T^2=T$.